# How can I store two different values in a byte [] into two doubles? C#

Tags: c#, byte

I gather data from my BLE and i recieve it nicely. From my BLE i send my two different values like this:

```
String valueOne = String(5.56749);
String valueTwo = String(2.24759);
BTLEserial.print(valueOne);
BTLEserial.print(valueTwo);
```

I send it like two different strings.

And when I receive it in my C# code it is a byte [].

And this is how I succesfully recieve it with my C# code.

```
RXcharacteristics.ValueUpdated += (sender, e) =>
{
    var result = e.Characteristic.Value; //result is a System.Byte []
    var str = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(result, 0, result.Length);
    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(str);
};
```

With that code I now get the two values stacked up underneath each other just like this in the log:

```
5.56749
2.24759
```

And that is maybe a little bit weird because in `GetString(result, 0, result.Length);`I have index as 0 which i thought would only get the first value so in my case I would only get `5.56749`in the log but I get them both.

What I now try to do is store them as unique doubles. I have started with something like this:

```
double valueOne;
double valueTwo;

valueOne = Convert.ToDouble(str.Split(' ').First());
valueTwo = Convert.ToDouble (str.Split(' ').Last());
```

But I get a crash: `Input string was not in correct format` on both `valueOne`and `valueTwo`.

I assume that I get it because the two different values are not seen as one string?

So what do I need to do in order to successfully store two values in my byte [] to doubles?

Comment: Need some more code to help you, but have you tried debugging and inspecting the value of `str` when you attempt to convert it to a double.

Comment: Please read [MCVE] guidance and [edit] the post to remove unrelated code and instead provide code that *just shows the problem*. I.e. with hardcoded byte array or simply const string showing value you can't parse to doubles. Note that you current code hints that there is absolutly no `'/'` in the string - so expecting `Split` to do anything may be a stretch...

Comment: Yea I posted that by mistake, should be `(' ')`. I will try to upload more code, but what exactly should i show more? More info about the ble device and how i send it or show how i get the connection with the ble? I do not have a lot more code to show that is related to the issue i think

Comment: Uploaded a little bit info about how i send the values from the BLE. I send the two values as strings one at a time

Comment: Why do you use `' '` in Split. I am pretty sure it should be '\r' or '\n' or '\r\n'.

Comment: Ok will try it! One second

Comment: `('\n')` If i use that I get the same error: "Input string is not in correct format"

Comment: I will try the others now

Comment: `('\r\n')` cant run this because it says: Too many characters in character literal

Comment: `('\r')` same error here, input string is not in correct format

Comment: tuse this splitting:  str.Split(new [] {Environment.NewLine}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)

Comment: Ok, i added it now. After I add that one, what do i need to add in order to store them in two different values?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you changed the data from the BLE to "1|value1" and "2|value2" you could use this:

```
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Received: " + str);
        String[] s = str.Split(new char[] { '|' });
        int index = int.Parse(s[0]);
        if (index == 1) {
            valueOne = double.Parse(s[1], System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
        }
        else if (index == 2) {
            valueTwo = double.Parse(s[1], System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
        }
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(valueOne);
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(valueTwo);
```